# Excel FILTER function: Want to search a row, but return data only from one column

Tags: excel, filter

I want to search `A4:AI4` for cells that match a certain value, but I want the formula to return only the content of `A4` as output. I've seen some discussions on nesting a FILTER function within another FILTER function, but I can't seem to get the formula to work. Any ideas?

Comment: There has to be more to this, because this is a simple if: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(ValToFind,A4:AI4,0)),A4,"")`

Comment: Could you provide some sample data plus an example for your expected output. Do you really mean  you want to return A4 - or do you mean, you want to return the filtered values for column A only (filter condition based on another column)?

Comment: Ultimately yes I want to return the values from column A, either separated by commas or cascading into separate cells. More background: this is a vacation week draft system where individuals pick specific weeks (identified by numbers) during each round. I want to have a section that shows a list of individuals (identified by initials) who selected each week. For example: 1: SB, FC, MC... 2: MD, BD, AD...

Comment: The "A" column is the individuals' initials. Each row consists of the individuals' week selections. Each column from "B" onwards represents the rounds.

Comment: I'm making progress by using TEXTJOIN in combination with Scott Craner's suggestion. I think it will get the job done but it's a pretty bulky formula: =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A90,$B$4:$AI$4,0)),$A$4,""),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A90,$B$5:$AI$5,0)),$A$5,""),IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A90,$B$6:$AI$6,0)),$A$6,""),...and so on...          if anyone has a more elegant solution I'll take it.